# Android Studio Google Map Markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So, I have built a Fusion Table on the GDRIVE, then exported the KML file
then...I have imported the KML file into my onMapReady with:

```
private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
    System.out.println("begin retrieveFileFromResouce()");
       try {
              mGoogleMap = getMap();
              kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, filename,     getApplicationContext());
kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();
                 }    catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
  }
```

The markers all come into the map....

I've created the code

```
 mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                            //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                            System.out.println("begin getInfoContents");
                            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
```

when I run the apk....the 1st Marker fills the infowindow....but the 2nd marker click uses the default window and will not show the .setText values that appear in the infoWindow....

how does the KML file "addMarker"??.....tie into the concept of the infoWindow??

I have gone so far as to extract the data from the KML file into just a text file, and can get the values with parsing code....but I don't understand how to associate your "data objects" to your Markers in a HashMap from either the text file or the KML file....

I would sincerely appreciate ANY suggestions.

Thanks